# How do I consume WCF service method in Excel 2010 that sends List<Car>?

Tags: wcf, excel

```
public List<Car> GetCars()
{
//returns list of cars
}
```

This is my WCF method.

```
public class Car
{

public int Doors{get;set;}
public string Make {get;set;}
}
```

This is the Car object

WCF service is deployed on IIS and is working and runs.
How do I consume this WCF service in Excel, take the returned list?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Consuming WCF service within MS office ?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/36f29920-aca0-4801-b65d-c925c847dde2)

> This is most certainly possible - we have be doing this since Office
>   2007 was first released. There are a number of approaches you could
>   take to achieve this depending on the programming model that you wish
>   to use, ie VBA or VSTO. Which model you decide to use is dependent on
>   a number of factors including exactly what you wish to achieve in
>   Office, what level of automation or UI interaction you wish to employ
>   and largely what you have doen so far. There is very good guidance on
>   this type of decision on MSDN's Office site.